# How do I pass data from a Laravel Blade file to a Vue instance?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a *.blade.php file which sends a GET request to an API. This returns a *.xml file which I am able to parse into the data to be used within the *.blade.php file. How do I go about passing this information to a *.vue file within my application? I've tried passing the data as a prop, but it doesn't seem to work correctly. Is there a best practice to handle this type of task?

**home.blade.php**

```
<?php 
@extends('layouts.app')

// <PHP API REQUEST HERE>

$example = data stored from XML file;
?>

@section('content')

<app :example ="example"></app>

@endsection
```

**app.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
{{ example }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>    
export default {    
    data() {
        return {    

        }
    },

    props: ['example']
}
<script>
```

Comment: you don't pass the data to the .vue file, but to the vue app, which will handle it there and pass to the component you have in the blade file

Comment: Am i going about passing the data incorrectly? <app> is a component I'm getting this error when trying to access the data within the <app> component. **"Property or method "example" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option."**  my vue app is created within my app.js file **"const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    store
});"**

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a problem with your approach.

First of all, don't make HTTP requests in your blade files, do it in the controller, then pass data as variables to blade `view('index', ['data' => 'array'])`.

Second point: if you want to pass simple data from PHP to Javascript, use `echo` in a script, example:

```
<script>
    window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]); ?>
</script>
```

Finally, for your particular case, you should have an API endpoint in Laravel that makes the HTTP request, and call it with an AJAX request from Vue JS.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll start to do some research on how to implement these methods.